# How should I remove the id from the database completely with the comma?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table `tbl_scripts` that goes like this:

```
 allowed_group_ids
+-----------------+
 12343,12343,21342
```

And I need to remove from this string a group id, for example 12343. Setting `delete_group_id` to `12343`, the below query seems to work correctly:

```
UPDATE tbl_scripts
SET allowed_group_ids = 
  REPLACE(
    REPLACE(allowed_group_ids, '$delete_group_id,', ''),
    ',$delete_group_id', '')
WHERE
  system_id = {$_SESSION['system_id']}
```

But if the column only has a single value, it fails:

```
 allowed_group_ids
+-----------------+
 12343 <-----I'm not able to replace this with blank
```

I know I should normalize the table, but at the moment I can't change my database structure, so I'm trying to make it work this way. How can I make my query work with single values?

Comment: The table would be better off being properly normalised, and then you'd never have these kind of problems

Comment: @MarkBaker sorry I forgot to mention but as my requirement I dont want to normalize my database

Comment: if you are deleting a single value, what do you want to replace it with?

Comment: Can that column have a `null`? Plus you have two `replaces`. So when there's nothing to replace... it fails, in that case you may want to check the length of the string or do a `instr` to check if there's a comma...

Comment: I want to replace with nothing, you can already read my query but what am doing is am replacing the id with a comma before or after but when the value is single am not able to replace as there's no comma

Comment: @Random Guy - I can never understand why people have this requirement - it's never better to wade through a mass of problems than to simplify the database and eliminate the problems in one go

Comment: @MarkBaker If I explain you for the work am using for you'll say oh yes you are using this for a right thing

Comment: anyway, MySQL is not that good in processing strings. You better handle replaces on PHP side: fetch the column, explode, remove the value from the array, implode, update.

Comment: You can try to use a select statement on the table and use string replace from php then update mysql, its low tech workaround for your problem

Comment: did you set the column to allow null values?

Comment: @Random Guy Your quote below - "you can see my profile how many times I've struggled to accomplish this" tells me that it's a massive problem, so I'm not going to even consider saying that handling unnormalised data is the right thing

Comment: @RandomGuy since this question got some downvotes, i edited it to make it better...pls check if it's okay, I hope I didn't change the meaning

Comment: @MarkBaker I bet you, if I explain you my thing you'll say you should use the way your are doing..

Answer (score 0):

The first replace searches for a trailing comma, the second for a leading comma.  The single group id has no trailing comma.

Safest option is to run a second query for the case where the field = value

doing this at any point

```
REPLACE(allowed_group_ids, '$delete_group_id', '')
```

May delete parts of longer ids (e.g. 123456 out of 1234567 would leave 7)
So don't do that

Alternatively always add a trailing comma even for single ids, then you only need something like

```
REPLACE(allowed_group_ids, '$delete_group_id,', '')
```

Adding a trailing comma, is something that you can easily update across the whole db, (as a one off query)

```
UPDATE table SET allowed_group_ids = CONCAT(allowed_group_ids, ',');
```

Then check through your code for insert and udpate statement acting on this table

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE tbl_scripts SET allowed_group_ids = 
TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REPLACE(allowed_group_ids, '$delete_group_id', ''))
WHERE system_id = {$_SESSION['system_id']}
```

This will remove every entry of `$delete_group_id` then cleanup leading and trailing commas with the `TRIM` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, not sure how feasible this is in terms of syntax wise..

```
UPDATE tbl_scripts SET allowed_group_ids = 
CASE WHEN INSTR(allowed_group_ids, '$delete_group_id,') > 0 THEN
REPLACE(REPLACE(allowed_group_ids, '$delete_group_id,', ''), ',$delete_group_id', '')
ELSE NULL END
WHERE system_id = {$_SESSION['system_id']}
;


UPDATE tbl_scripts SET allowed_group_ids = 
CASE WHEN INSTR(allowed_group_ids, ',') > 0 THEN
REPLACE(REPLACE(allowed_group_ids + ',', '$delete_group_id,', ''), ',$delete_group_id', ''
ELSE
REPLACE(REPLACE(allowed_group_ids, '$delete_group_id,', ''), ',$delete_group_id', '')
END
AND system_id = {$_SESSION['system_id']}
;
```

Comment: Check if the column has only one value, then add a comma to the end, then replace :) try that

Comment: even a single person cant get this thing right, you can see my profile how many times I've struggled to accomplish this

Comment: :( I sorry, may be you can try other solutions give here :) anything that works for you. What @Quassnoi said makes sense, if you can do the string manupilations in PHP side.. :$

Comment: I guess that will be the better way, fetch, explode, remove, update

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do what you are looking for:

```
UPDATE tbl_scripts
SET allowed_group_ids =
  TRIM( both ',' from
  REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
      CONCAT(',',
        REPLACE(allowed_group_ids, ',', ',,')
           , ','), ',12343,', '')
    , ',,', ','))
```

- first I double every `,` to `,,`
- then I add a `,` before the string and a `,` after, to make it easyer to match the group to delete
- then I replace all `,delete_group_id,` (with leading and trailing commas) with an empty string
- then I replace again all `,,` back to single `,`
- with TRIM, i remove leading and trailing `,`

Comment: will try and let you know :)

Comment: @RandomGuy did you try my answer?